# How to group data on the YAxis of a .NET chart?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, charts

I have a .NET Chart which currently looks like this:

[image]

Here is the code used to generate it:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
  // Set Chart properties
  ganttChart.Width = 800;
  ganttChart.Height = 500;

  // Create Chart Area
  var area = new ChartArea();      
  ganttChart.ChartAreas.Add(area);
  ganttChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Angle = 30; // For some unknown reason Y-Axis is actually the X-Axis
  ganttChart.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.LabelStyle.Format = "HH:mm dd/MMM";;

   // Set up some data
  var dt = new DataTable();
  dt.Columns.Add("Name", typeof(string));
  dt.Columns.Add("SeriesID", typeof(double));
  dt.Columns.Add("y", typeof(DateTime));
  dt.Columns.Add("y2", typeof(DateTime));
  dt.Rows.Add("A", 1, new DateTime(2015, 10, 22, 8, 0, 0), new DateTime(2015, 10, 22, 9, 0, 0));
    dt.Rows.Add("A", 1, new DateTime(2015, 10, 22, 10, 0, 0), new DateTime(2015, 10, 22, 12, 0, 0));
    dt.Rows.Add("A", 1, new DateTime(2015, 10, 22, 18, 0, 0), new DateTime(2015, 10, 22, 20, 0, 0));
  dt.Rows.Add("B", 2, new DateTime(2015, 10, 22, 8, 30, 0), new DateTime(2015, 10, 22, 9, 13, 0));
    dt.Rows.Add("B", 2, new DateTime(2015, 10, 22, 17, 0, 0), new DateTime(2015, 10, 22, 18, 43, 0));
  dt.Rows.Add("C", 3, new DateTime(2015, 10, 22, 13, 0, 0), new DateTime(2015, 10, 22, 14, 0, 0));
    dt.Rows.Add("C", 3, new DateTime(2015, 10, 22, 14, 22, 0), new DateTime(2015, 10, 22, 14, 32, 0));

  var series = new Series();
  series.Name = "Series1";
  series.ChartType = SeriesChartType.RangeBar;
  series.YValueType = ChartValueType.DateTime;

  // Add the series to the chart
  ganttChart.Series.Add(series);
  ganttChart.Series[series.Name].Points.DataBind(dt.Select(), "SeriesID", "y,y2", "Label=Name");
  ganttChart.Series[series.Name].Label = "Y = Name";

}
```

What I want to achieve is the Name field of the datatable to be the label on the Y-Axis, so that along the left hand side of the chart you see A, B & C instead of 0,1,2,3,4.

If I change the DataBind method use Name instead of series ID then I get the affect that I'm after but then I loose the Y-Axis grouping. It ends up looking like this:

[image]

What I need is a happy medium where the grouping is like the first picture and the labels are like the second. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Did you ever find a resolution to this problem?

Comment: I did. I'll post it as an answer now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution to my problem was not to rely on DataBinding and instead create each point manually and add it to the series myself. This way I had much more control over the properties of each point.

I made a method called MapDataRowToDataPoint which looked like this:

```
private DataPoint MapDataRowToDataPoint(DataRow row)
{
  try{
    var point = new DataPoint();

    point.XValue = double.Parse(row["SeriesID"].ToString());
    point.YValues = new double[]{
        Convert.ToDateTime(row["Y1"].ToString()).ToOADate(), 
        Convert.ToDateTime(row["Y2"].ToString()).ToOADate()
    };
    point.AxisLabel = row["SeriesName"].ToString(); 
    point.Color = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#" + row["Colour"].ToString());
    point.BorderWidth = 1;
    point.BorderColor = Color.Black;
    point.ToolTip = row["ToolTip"].ToString()
                    + ((!string.IsNullOrEmpty(row["ToolTip"].ToString()))?"\n":"")
                    + "Start Date Time: #VALY{"+toolTipDateTimeFormat+"}\n" 
                    +"End Date Time:   #VALY2{"+toolTipDateTimeFormat+"}";
    point.IsValueShownAsLabel = false;
    point.PostBackValue = row["PostBackValue"].ToString();

    return point;
  }
  catch
  {
    //Log the error
    return null;
  }
}
```

Here you can see I map a row of my datatable to a DataPoint object and can control each property of the data point in great detail.

Now, instead of databinding, I loop through each row of my data source and call the above method, then add the point to the chart's series:

```
// For each row of the DataSource, create a data point and add it to the chart
  foreach(DataRow row in data.Rows)
  {
    var point = MapDataRowToDataPoint(row);
    if(point != null)
      ganttChart.Series[0].Points.Add(point);
  }
```

This method proved much more painless than relying on data binding. Hope this helps!